# How can I import the data in my array list to a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way by which I can create a JTable using the data in an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880722/is-there-any-way-by-which-i-can-create-a-jtable-using-the-data-in-an-arraylist)

The code of my program is as follows:

```
//A loan Amortization example
public class LoanTable 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double p,n,r,a,rb,ia,pa,pno=1;

    //creating a double arraylist
    List<double[]> l = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    p=250000;
    n=360;
    r=0.416/100;
    a=1342.05;

    rb=p;

//calculating the amount as interest, amount as principal and remaining balance 
    for(int i=1; i<=n;i++)
    {
        ia=(rb*r);
        pa=a-ia;
        rb=rb-pa;

        l.add(new double[] { pno,a,ia,pa,rb });

        pno++;

    }

    for (double[] row : l) 
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));

    }

}
}
```

How do I import the values in the rows to create a table? It becomes difficult to import the values.

The output is somewhat like :

[1.0, 1342.05, 1040.0, 302.04999999999995, 249697.95]

[2.0, 1342.05, 1038.7434719999999, 303.30652800000007, 249394.64347200003]

[3.0, 1342.05, 1037.48171684352, 304.56828315648, 249090.07518884353]

[4.0, 1342.05, 1036.214712785589, 305.835287214411, 248784.23990162913]

[5.0, 1342.05, 1034.942437990777, 307.1075620092229, 248477.13233961992]

[6.0, 1342.05, 1033.6648705328187, 308.3851294671813, 248168.74721015274]

[7.0, 1342.05, 1032.3819883942353, 309.6680116057646, 247859.07919854697]

[8.0, 1342.05, 1031.0937694659553, 310.9562305340446, 247548.12296801293]

[9.0, 1342.05, 1029.8001915469338, 312.2498084530662, 247235.87315955988]

[10.0, 1342.05, 1028.501232343769, 313.5487676562309, 246922.32439190365]

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?? How do you want to display them?

Comment: I want the output in a JTable with the data in this arraylist...

Comment: But I don't see any JTable here.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you have to implement arraydriven model

Comment: Thats the problem. I dod not know how to import all this data into a JTable. A JTable has a fixed number of rows and columns. Any idea how I could import it? 

As of now, I have created this arraylist which displays the data. But it would be better, if I could display this data in a JTable.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the `List<double[]>` as backing data in an `AbstractTableModel`. There are plenty of [good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303680/java-swing-extend-abstracttablemodel-and-use-it-with-jtable-several-question) of this table model available online.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing to understand while working with *JTable* is that every JTable is internally backed by a *TableModel*. If you're new to using tables, I would suggest ["How to Use Tables"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as a good place to start learning about the implementation

Every table model basically implements the TableModel interface. For your scenario, you should look at creating your own table model, extending the [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) class. As per the javadoc,

> To create a concrete TableModel as a subclass of AbstractTableModel
> you need only provide implementations for the following three methods:
>
> **public int getRowCount();**    
> **public int getColumnCount();** 
> **public Object getValueAt(int row, int column);**

So your implementation of TableModel will be *minimally* something like this [*note that I said minimally because there're other methods of this class that you would also want to override, for example getColumnNames(...)*]:

```
import java.util.List;  
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    
    private List<double[]> dataList;
    
    public MyTableModel(List<double[]> dataList){
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return (dataList.size() > 0) ? dataList.get(0).length : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        
        if(rowIndex < dataList.size()){
            double[] columns = dataList.get(rowIndex);
            if(columns.length > columnIndex){
                return columns[columnIndex];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```